# BQ STRUCT versus RECORD types?

Tags: google-bigquery

May be a very trivial question.
What is the actual difference between STRUCT and RECORD types in GCP BigQuery? Can I use them interchangably? If I have a table created with a column defined as STRUCT, will it show a "schema" mismatch if I try to re-run a Terraform script with the field type changed to RECORD?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated - _"To create a column with nested and repeated data, set the data type of the column to RECORD. A RECORD is stored as a STRUCT and can be accessed as a STRUCT in standard SQL. A STRUCT is a container of ordered fields each with a type (required) and a name (optional). To make the column nested, you add child fields to the RECORD (parent). To make the column repeated, change the mode to REPEATED."_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe they are mostly the same thing, or you may view them as same concept in different components of BigQuery.

For historical reasons the Legacy SQL and storage documentation talks mostly about RECORD, while Standard SQL dialect uses STRUCT.

A column created with Standard SQL DDL as STRUCT will appear as RECORD in storage UI, and Terraform script using RECORD should be compatible.